# GitHub Actions run on push to all branches

Tags: continuous-integration, glob, github-actions

It's [easy](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-a-list-of-events) to run a GitHub Action on any push or pull request:

```yaml
# Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events
on: [push, pull_request]
```

But what if I want to restrict runs to pull requests opened against specific base refs, while allowing runs on all branches?

I thought about this:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "*"
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "develop"
      - "staging"
```

But it didn't work. I added this Action to a feature branch and GitHub didn't pick it up.

Is there anything wrong with my glob? Why doesn't '*' work?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I found the [Filter pattern cheat sheet](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet) after posting the question:

> '*': Matches all branch and tag names that don't contain a slash (/).
> The * character is a special character in YAML. When you start a pattern > with *, you must use quotes.
>
> '**': Matches all branch and tag names. This is the default behavior
> when you don't use a branches or tags filter.

It happened that the branch I was testing contained a slash (/), so one asterisk (*) wasn't enough. I switched to two asterisks (**) and it works now.

Comment: You can also drop the `branches` object completely to trigger on events for any branch.

Comment: The yml file doesn't compile when I remove `branches`, because `on` is a mapping.

Comment: Don't you also have to merge the .YML file to ALL the branches so the triggers actually work for each named branch?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Try using `on: {}`

Comment: This works for me: `branches: []`

Answer (score 31):

Dropping the restrictions on pushes entirely means triggering on all of them (commits, and also tags):

```yaml
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
      - staging

jobs:
  print:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "Running!"
```

Comment: Note: when you drop `branches`, the workflow will run for tag pushes as well, not only for branch pushes.

Comment: @Suma Good point, added a remark to point this out.